# Roofing plywood - proper staggering / cutting of sheets

Tags: roof, plywood

Is this the correct way to lay out plywood to fit a 12x10 roof?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per https://www.nachi.org/inspect-roof-sheathing.htm

> Plywood panels should be laid with the face grain perpendicular to the rafter boards. The panels should be installed over two or more spans, with the long dimension or strength axis oriented across the rafter boards or truss cords.

Your layout plan seems to meet this criteria so you should be good.

I've seen discussions about whether or not to stagger the seams and it appears to be common practice. It's effectiveness is debatable. Personally, I would feel better with staggered seams like you have.

That page has other considerations as well so make sure to read everything.